# Consumo de memória em java

Tags: java

Usando o Java, desejo referenciar algumas variáveis, nomeadamente objectos em outras classes, e estou preocupado com o consumo de memória. Será que o numero de referencias de um objecto afeta, ou redobra a memória?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Será que o numero de referencias de um objecto afeta, ou redobra a memória?

Se olharmos atentamente a essa frase, podemos identificar que não estamos falando de uma variável de OBJETO, mas, sim, de uma **variável de referência** a um objeto.

Uma **variável de referência** contém bits que representam uma maneira de acessar um objeto, uma espécie de ponteiro (no mundo java, há muita discussão se é ponteiro ou referência... mas são discussões que por ora, deixaremos para academia).

Bom... o que isso quer dizer? A **variável de referência** não contém um objeto propriamente dito, mas algo como um endereço para esse objeto, o tal do ponteiro, e a JVM sabe como usar essa referência para chegar ao objeto.

No geral, não sabemos como a JVM específica (porque podem haver várias implementações de JVM) implementa as referências de objeto. Elas podem ser um ponteiro que aponte para outro ponteiro que aponta para.... mas mesmo que você saiba como isso é implementado, não poderá usar esses bits para nenhuma outra finalidade que não seja acessar um objeto.

Então se para cada **variável de referência**, a JVM precisa alocar bits de memória, concluímos que haverá consumo de memória para cada **variável de referência**, agora quantos bits serão alocados, você teria que ler os documentos de implementação da JVM utilizada.

Por outro lado, sempre que um objeto Java é criado, ele vai para uma área de memória conhecida como **HEAP**. Todos os objetos independente de quando, como e onde sejam criados, eles irão residir lá no **HEAP**. Quando você cria um objeto, o Java alocará espaço na memória **HEAP** de acordo com quanto esse objeto específico vai precisar. Um objeto com 15 **variáveis de instância**, provavelmente precisará de mais espaço do que um objeto com duas.

Mas e como esse objeto sai do **HEAP**?  O java que irá gerenciar essa memória pra você, ou seja, quando a JVM identificar que um objeto pode nunca mais ser utilizado, ele se torna qualificado para o **Garbage Collector**, caso você esteja ficando sem memória ele também será acionado.

E como a JVM identifica que o objeto pode não ser mais utilizado? Quando a **variável de referência** estiver liberada ou seja, não utilizada.

Segue um trecho de código bem simples:

```
 Person person_01 = new Person("Thiago");
    Person person_02 = person_01;
    Person person_03 = person_01;
    Person person_04 = person_01;
    Person person_05 = person_01;
    Person person_06 = person_01;
    Person person_07 = person_01;
    Person person_08 = person_01;
    Person person_09 = person_01;
    Person person_10 = person_01;

    System.out.println(person_01);
    System.out.println(person_02);
    System.out.println(person_03);
    System.out.println(person_04);
    System.out.println(person_05);
    System.out.println(person_06);
    System.out.println(person_07);
    System.out.println(person_08);
    System.out.println(person_09);
    System.out.println(person_10);
```

O Java teve que alocar dez **variáveis de referências**, mas somente um objeto. As dez **variáveis de referência** apontam para o mesmo objeto, ou seja, no **HEAP** foi alocado somente um objeto.

Bom isso é o básico do entendimento de como o Java gerência suas memórias. Existe muito mais, existem técnicas avançadas para não depender tanto de **Gargabe Collector**, e se formos aprofundar mais na JVM, vai extender demais o texto.

[Doc Garbage Collector](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

[Doc Gerênciamento de Memória](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html)

**Referências e Sugestões de Leitura**

1. *Livro Use a Cabeça Java (Kathy Sierra & Bert Bates)*
2. *Imergindo na JVM (Otávio Santana)*
3. *Introdução à Arquitetura e Desing de Software (Paulo Silveira, Guilherme Silveira, Sérgio Lopes, Guilherme Moreira, Nico Steppat, Fabio Kung)*

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Meu irmão, muito obrigado pela informação detalhada.